# How to access two servers on one domain

Tags: html, networking, lamp

Port 80 is forwarded to a server on my network which has links to the different projects I'm working on, how could I allow people to connect to the server running on my laptop when I'm using it? I would obviously not prefer to change my router settings frequently to port forward to my laptop. I want the user to access my domain and maybe have a set of links which will be described as static and another set which will have a description cautioning the user that said links will only work when I am online and they would somehow redirect to my laptop. (Lamp Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understood correctly your question, you should configure your laptop as a reverse proxy for your main server. 

As you said, you should have a set of links which will redirect to your laptop (via reverse proxy config), but of course these links will work only when your laptop is available.

Comment: How do I reference the other server? if `www.example.com` is my domain how would I access a page on `192.168.1.10` on my network with a link on a homepage. What would the 'href` be or is there more work involved?

Comment: Your server is on the same network as the laptop?

Comment: Yes, but I was able to find it. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You could use either the host in href, e.g. a href="http://192.168.1.10" but in this case you have access only to the href page, either with reverse proxy config, this way you can access any page from your laptop.